# ng-submit won't call function inside directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

ok, i think the question says it all, but just to be clear, i have the following form (I know it's long... I'm using bootstrap... and jquery):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="cal.addEvent()"novalidate>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="title">Title:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"> 
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Event Title" ng-model="cal.newEvent.title">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="desc">Description:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"> 
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" placeholder="Event Description" ng-model="cal.newEvent.description">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="stime">Start Time:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"> 
              <input type="time" class="form-control" id="stime" ng-model="cal.newEvent.start">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="etime">End Time:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8"> 
              <input type="time" class="form-control" id="etime" ng-model="cal.newEvent.end">
            </div>
          </div>

          </div>
          <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"  data-role="none">Add Event</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

this form is inside a directive which looks like this:

```
app.directive("calendar", function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "templates/calendar.html",
        scope: true,
        transclude:true,
        link: function(scope)  {
            //there's a bunch of code here that I don't believe has anything to do with ng-submit so i left it out
        },
        controller: ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope){
            this.newEvent = {};

            this.removeEvent = function(index){
            $http.post("classes/main.php", {"fn": "calendarDel", "id": $scope.chosen[index].id}).success(function(data){
                $scope.getEvents($scope.chosen[index].date);
            });
            }

            this.addEvent = function(){
                //this.newEvent.date = $scope.dateString;
                console.log("AddEvent");
                console.log(this.newEvent);
            }
            $scope.getEvents = function(date){
                $http.post("classes/main.php", {"fn": "calendar", "id": $rootScope.user.id, "data": date}).success(function(data){
                    if(!data.Error){
                    $scope.chosen = data;
                    }
                });

            }
        }],
        controllerAs: 'cal'
    };
});
```

the problem is that when i try to submit my form, i see no indication that the function has been called... i expect to at least see `console.log("AddEvent");`

does anybody see what may be causing this problem here?

---

**FYI**

the form is in a bootstrap 3 modal div, which is inside the same directive it's called from --- if you need to see the "bigger picture", so to speak, just ask :)

i have tried `this.addEvent()`, `$scope.addEvent()`, `$rootScope.addEvent()` no change

Answer (score 1):

You should just be calling `addEvent()`

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addEvent()" novalidate>
```

and bind the function to your scope like

```
$scope.addEvent = function() {
```

From the angular docs on [expresssions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

> expressions are evaluated against a scope object

so you should not write the expression as `ng-submit="$scope.addEvent()"` etc

Comment: @JamieMcAllister it works in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iO8bGml24kH4yNd2mvw7?p=preview). Perhaps you can create a plunker for us to take a look

Answer (score 1):

You should add `bindToController: true` to the directive and specify `scope: {}` to create an isolate scope.

> When an isolate scope is used for a component (see above), and controllerAs is used, bindToController: true will allow a component to have its properties bound to the controller, rather than to scope. When the controller is instantiated, the initial values of the isolate scope bindings are already available.

Reference: [`$compile`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-)